# Python воспринимает 1 обратный слеш как 2, поэтому пишет что файл не найден

Tags: python

```
with open("C:\old\Files\Скрипты\Python\мини проекты\Python\мини проекты\stat.json", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as STAT:
    Стата = load(STAT)
```

есть следующий код, имеется по одному слешу, но как запускаю код то вместо одного слеша выводит два, из-за чего выводит ошибку, что файл не найден. Вот сама ошибка:

```
Возникло исключение: FileNotFoundError

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\old\\Files\\Скрипты\\Python\\мини проекты\\Python\\мини проекты\\stat.json'
```

Comment: Проблема в чём-то другом, сами по себе бэкслеши похоже нормально обработались, у вас или кодировка скрипта другая чем у названия файлов в системе, а может где-то пробелы другие, чем они видятся, а может вообще где-то лишний пробел в названии файла или каталога, а вы без него путь набираете. Для начала попробуйте положить ваш файл по пути `C:\old\stat.json` и прочитать оттуда. И постепенно двигайтесь вглубь по пути, там и выяснится что не так - русские буквы в пути, пробелы или ещё что-то. Но при этом всё же используйте r-строки либо двойные либо прямые слеши.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1: Два обратных слеша

```
with open("C:\\old\\Files\\Скрипты\\Python\\мини проекты\\Python\\мини проекты\\stat.json", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as STAT:
    Стата = load(STAT)
```

Вариант 2: Префикс r

```
with open(r"C:\old\Files\Скрипты\Python\мини проекты\Python\мини проекты\stat.json", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as STAT:
    Стата = load(STAT)
```

Comment: Я по вашему на хрустальном шаре должен гадать что префикс `r` делает? Напишите про него, из вашего ответа ничего не понятно. Бонусом можно написать про экранирование, для тех кто ещё не знает.

Answer (score 2):

Обратный слеш специальный символ, он применяется для экранирования других символов. Попробуйте продублировать их:

```
with open("C:\\old\\...\\...")
```

Или обыкновенные слеши могут помочь:

```
with open("C:/old/.../...")
```

Comment: / - слэш, \\  - обратный слэш

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию `join` из стандартного модуля `os` (см. [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)).
Пути в Windows имеют свои особенности. Как эти особенности учесть, показано [в этом решении](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422798/python-os-path-join-on-windows), согласно которому абсолютный путь в ОС следует составлять так:

```py
import os

# Указание абсолютных путей:
# - в Windows
mypath = os.path.join('c:/', 'somedir', 'somefile.json')
# - в Linux и др.
mypath = os.path.join('/', 'home', 'somedir', 'somefile.json')
```

И полученный путь `mypath` использовать в операторе контекста `with`.